# ACF check if variable has http, if else return string

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

Trying to check if `$link` has `http://` in front of it or not. If someone puts in `www.google.com` for the link field it acts as a link within the WordPress site, ie: `www.website.com/www.google.com`.

```
$link = get_field('advertisement_link');

$ad_code = '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">Test</a>';
```

Sample code above I am working with. This is a general PHP question as well. How do I do this the right way? Tried below, replaces `the_content()` with the `$link`.

```
$link = get_field('advertisement_link');

if(strpos($link, 'http://') !== 0) {
    return 'http://' . $link;
} else {
    return $link;
}

$ad_code = '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">Test</a>';
```

Edit: I need to keep `$ad_code` because I'm using it inside `return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 3, $content );` to insert this ad into a post every 3 paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not `return` the value, but alter the varialbe `$link`

```
if(strpos($link, 'http://') !== 0) {
    $link = 'http://' . $link;
} //no else needed
```

Be aware that if your link begins with `https://` it will also prepend the `http://` and result in `http://https://example.com`.

The better way to do this would be from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2762083/1365666), adjusted to your needs:

In `functions.php`:

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Code for you:

```
$link = addhttp( get_field('advertisement_link') );
$ad_code = '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">Test</a>';
```

Comment: Worked! Can't thank you enough. Elegant way to parse the data through in a concise, easy to understand way. I replaced `$url` with `$link` which I assume is the correct way? Worked either way, though.

Comment: @AlexanderGraham you don't need to do that, as this variable is just used in this function. You can call it anything you want - even $wordpressstackexchange.com, as long as you use the same variable everywhere in this function.

Comment: understood, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a possible duplicate of – or at least similar to "[Checking if string contains HTTP://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487794/checking-if-string-contains-http)" over at stackoverflow – but still: First instead of checking for "0" you should check for "false". And then you should also check for "https://". I would probably do something like this:

```
if (substr($link, 0, 7) == 'http://') {
    // do nothing
} elseif (substr($link, 0, 8) == 'https://') {
    // do nothing
} else {
    $link = 'http://'.$link;
}
```

( I'm aware there are more elegant ways to write this )